# How to find the rankings in a leaderboard and turn it into a dictionary in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a nested leaderboard, like this:

```
[[100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10, 5], [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 25, 20, 10]]
```

I want to find the ranking in this leaderboard in the Dense Order Ranking method. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Dense_ranking_.28.221223.22_ranking.29

And I want to use the rankings and turn it into a dictionary but the scores needs to remain as the keys while the rankings as the values, like this:

```
[{100:1,100:1,50:2,40:3,40:3,20:4,10:5,5:6},{100:1,100:1,50:2,40:3,40:3,25:4,20:5,10:6}]
```

How can I achieve this using Python3?

Comment: You realize that `{100:1,100:1,50:2,40:3,40:3,20:4,10:5,5:6}` will become `{100:1,50:2,40:3,20:4,10:5,5:6}` since `dict` objects must have unique keys?

Comment: You can't do exactly that with a dictionary. I think you should tell us what further processing you plan to do with this data. Without knowing that we can't suggest an alternative data structure.

Comment: You just [deleted your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423146/how-to-put-the-numbers-from-one-list-to-another-list-but-in-descending-order). Same format: you think that SO works like: "I post my problem" - "you solve it".That _might_ work, but it is bad form. I suggest rereading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and providing your try as [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Deleting questions voided the work put into solving _your_ problem by 3 ppl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, your expected data structure is not a dictionary because it contains duplicates keys. Instead you can create a list of tuples. You can use a counter object and a dictionary to keep track of seen items and their respective index to create that tuple.

The following function is an understandable implementation of aforementioned method that creates the expected result in one iteration.

```
In [38]: from itertools import count
In [38]: def ranker(lst):
    ...:     for sub in lst:
    ...:         seen = {}
    ...:         c = count()
    ...:         next(c)
    ...:         ss = []
    ...:         for j in sub:
    ...:             try:
    ...:                 ind = seen[j]
    ...:             except KeyError:
    ...:                 ind = seen[j] = next(c)
    ...:             ss.append((j, ind))
    ...:         yield ss
```

Demo:

```
In [39]: lst
Out[39]: [[100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10, 5], [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 25, 20, 10]]

In [40]: list(ranker(lst))
Out[40]: 
[[(100, 1), (100, 1), (50, 2), (40, 3), (40, 3), (20, 4), (10, 5), (5, 6)],
 [(100, 1), (100, 1), (50, 2), (40, 3), (40, 3), (25, 4), (20, 5), (10, 6)]]
```

Now one very more Pythonic but a little bit obscurer approach is to instead of using `counter` and a `try-except` block and even the list and appending using a `dict.setdefault()` method within a list comprehension as following:

```
In [43]: def ranker(lst):
    ...:     for sub in lst:
    ...:         seen = {}
    ...:         yield [(j, seen.setdefault(j, len(seen) + 1)) for j in sub]
```

The `dict.setdefault()` method returns the respective value for the first argument if its present in dictionary otherwise update itself with second argument (`len(seen) + 1`) as its value and returns it.

Demo:

```
In [44]: list(ranker(lst))
Out[44]: 
[[(100, 1), (100, 1), (50, 2), (40, 3), (40, 3), (20, 4), (10, 5), (5, 6)],
 [(100, 1), (100, 1), (50, 2), (40, 3), (40, 3), (25, 4), (20, 5), (10, 6)]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A less performant but succinct solution is possible using dictionary and list comprehensions:

```
lst = [[100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10, 5], [100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 25, 20, 10]]

dicts = [{v: k for k, v in dict(enumerate(reversed(sorted(set(i))), 1)).items()}\
         for i in lst]

res = [[(n, dicts[i][n]) for n in j] for i, j in enumerate(lst)]
```

---

For performance, I recommend you use a 3rd party library such as `numpy` or `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(lst).T
ranks = data.rank(method='dense', axis=0, ascending=False).astype(int)

res = [list(zip(data[i], ranks[i])) for i in range(len(data.columns))]

[[(100, 1), (100, 1), (50, 2), (40, 3), (40, 3), (20, 4), (10, 5), (5, 6)],
 [(100, 1), (100, 1), (50, 2), (40, 3), (40, 3), (25, 4), (20, 5), (10, 6)]]
```